# SQLite query is not returning true value

Tags: android, sqlite

I entered the following code for comparing the records with the database records. It is executing but it shows already exists for every entering record (it may be an old or new record.)

```
boolean ifExisting() {
      //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE  category='"+str1+"'",null);

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE"  + "category" + "=" + category,null);


        Integer a=new Integer(c.getCount());

      Log.e("getcount",a.toString());
         if(c.getCount()>-1)
        { return false;} 
    else{
         return true;
    }
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2):

put a space after WHERE:

```
 "SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE "  + "category" + "=" + category,null
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

1. Your WHERE-clause is concatenating the word `category` with the word `WHERE`.
2. Does the `Integer` function do any kind of rationalisation of the value passed to it, which might affect what gets assigned to `a`?
3. You display `a`, but test `c.getCount()` - are these two values actually the same? (see point 2). Also, is `c.getCount()` still valid on the second call to it?
4. There's a `}` missing somewhere - is the function actually following the path you think it is?