# App gets Force Close upon running an SQL query

Tags: android, sqlite

I added a space after "WHERE" in my SQL query based on the advice in [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448512/its-not-returning-the-true-value).
However, now my app gets a "Force Close".

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE " + "category" + "=" + category,null);
```

Comment: Didn't got what you want to say. Describe your question properly. Give the error details.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448512/its-not-returning-the-true-value

Answer (score 1):

You should create queries like this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE category=?", 
                       new String[] {category});
```

This will do the proper quoting for you and save you from SQL injections attacks.

Also, whenever you see a Force Close, there is an unhandled Exception associated with it. You can see that in the LogCat (this is available in Eclipse's Debug perspective). The type and the message of the Exception are invaluable information for debugging the error.

Comment: If I may but in with my own question on this answer please, kgiannakakis. I've had chronic trouble with Android returning empty cursors (no SQLiteExceptions) when I made my queries in this way. Whenever I change them back to the other way (without using question marks) it works again. What could I be doing wrong? I've ended up just manually building query strings and sanitising my own input because this has been such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your query as kgiannakakis suggested.

For your problem, you have to surround your `category` value with single quotes such as :

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM  sharelist  WHERE "  + "category" + "='" + category + "'",null);
```